# How to use Xcode Logger with Swift

Tags: swift, logging

I've found [this library](https://github.com/codeFi/XcodeLogger) on Github which looks like a pretty neat replacement for NSLog but I don't know how to use it with Swift in my iOS project.

I've tried calling `XLog` or `DLog` in my functions but I get `use of unresolved identifier ...`. I allowed Xcode to create a bridging header and imported "XcodeLogger.h" there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I've dragged the files from the Core folder into my project and Xcode asked me if I want a bridging header. I selected Yes and imported XcodeLogger.h in there.

Comment: By the way Swift already offers a replacement for `NSLog`: `println` and `debugPrintln`.

Comment: Check out my logging framework: https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger

Comment: A bit late on this topic but if you want you can use mine logger https://github.com/nativ18/Swift-Extensions/blob/master/Logger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of the library, XLog and DLog are defined as macros:

```
#define XLog(input, ...)           func_XLog_Output(XLOGGER_TYPE_NSLOG,XLOGGER_LEVEL_SIMPLE,CALLEE,CALLEE_METHOD,FILE_NAME,LINE_NUMBER,input, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Unfortunately, Swift doesn't recognize these. The only way I know of getting around this would be to create an Objective-C class with static methods that calls the macros for you.